# i want to swap this messages from on by one to downside ,

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need help in this case, I am trying to give broadcast message to my clients.Tthat means I want to only send my inputs to the user in a form of messages, and don't want to take input from them. So what I did , I am using cloud messaging to my project, now I am able to take inputs firebase and display on my text view. But now I want to store that and swap it line by line to down side, I want to show my messages their only, also I want to show my only last 10 messages, so later part will be useless, I tried swapping but its not working in my chart.

I will show my activity here

MainActivity.java

```
package com.intraday.geeks;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;



    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        TextView textView1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.callOne);
        TextView textView2 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.CallTwo);
        TextView textView3 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.callThree);
        TextView textView4 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.callFour);
        TextView textView5 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.callFive);
        TextView textView6 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.callSix);
        TextView textView7 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.callSeven);
        TextView textView8 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.CallEight);


        if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null){
            for(String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet())
            {
                if (key.equals("a")){
                    textView1.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString(key));
                    String variable1 = textView1.getText().toString();



                }
            }


        }



    }



    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();



        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser==null){
            Intent authIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(authIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#5d1b8f"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.intraday.geeks.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/callOne"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="#dc2619"
        android:text="Tips are only Available In Live Market 9:15Am to 3:15Pm"
        style="@style/Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CallTwo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:text="Tips are only Available In Live Market 9:15Am to 3:15Pm"
        style="@style/Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat">

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/callThree"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="#dc2619"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:text="Tips are only Available In Live Market 9:15Am to 3:15Pm"
        style="@style/Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat">

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/callFour"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Tips are only Available In Live Market 9:15Am to 3:15Pm"
        style="@style/Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat">

    </TextView>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/callFive"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:background="#dc2619"
        android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="Tips are only Available In Live Market 9:15Am to 3:15Pm"
    style="@style/Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat">

</TextView>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/callSix"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:textColor="#ffff"

        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Tips are only Available In Live Market 9:15Am to 3:15Pm"
        style="@style/Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat">

    </TextView>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/callSeven"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="#dc2619"
        android:text="Tips are only Available In Live Market 9:15Am to 3:15Pm"
        style="@style/Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat">

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CallEight"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:textColor="#ffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Tips are only Available In Live Market 9:15Am to 3:15Pm"
        style="@style/Base.AlertDialog.AppCompat">

    </TextView>






</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: search::from firebase to listview

Comment: @Eminem i allready done that brother .. will you please help me.. i will pay for it

Comment: I will without payment,but I need at least 3h to finish my job

Comment: @Eminem please give me your mail or whatsapp number to contact you so , i will message you after 3 hrs

Comment: @dont worry I will help you

Comment: @Eminem thank you so much sir.. will be helpfull for me , i am trying fix this problem from last 7 hrs .. i need someones help

Comment: what do you mean `swap it line by line to down side`?

Comment: @Eminem i mean i want to show my messages to users , but dont want thier messages.. they should only watch my messages , like broadcast in whatsapp, 
I just created application , i can now get text from firebase and display on activity ..but also i want to store that text and swap it.. that means its should go , from textview2 , textview3 , textview4 ,, so on till textview10 ,and i want to disply it on activity .

Comment: but the text that you will display will already be stored in firebase,why store it a second time?basically you want only to get the values from firebase and display them in a listview am I right?I dont use whatsapp

Comment: I am using firebase cloud Messaging, not database , how can I access ?

Comment: you want to display notifications in a listview?or are you building a chat?

Comment: Yes i want to disply notification in listview yes , and later i want to show the history of last 10 or 15 notifications, 
Not chat application , i want to give broadcast

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48955689/display-firebase-notification-in-listview

Comment: http://www.zoftino.com/android-notification-data-messages-from-app-server-using-firebase-cloud-messaging

Comment: Thank you so much sir , where is the xml file sir.. because i dony know more about listview, so .

Comment: you can create it yourself,he has created a `listview` named `list_item` then you create a custom xml where you create two texts one called `title` and the other called `message`.I wished I could help you more but unfortunately I have never used FireBaseMessage,and from what I see,it looks like a big project.Start somewhere and when you are stuck,tell me again.I will help you as much as I can

Comment: Okay today i will add one list view and let you know , what is the next